# redirect to member page

Tags: php

I'm putting together user pages based on the username in the URL. for example blank.com/username

I was able to get a script to get the user name:

```
$pageName = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

now, when you got to blank.com/username it obviously takes you to a page that doesn't exist. how do I redirect to the page they are suppose to go to?

Comment: What is the page they are supposed to go to?

Comment: What page they are supposed to go to?

Comment: it should go to blank.com/q&a/holic.php?user=<?php echo $pageName ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using .htaccess to send the requests to your desired PHP file.  This is assuming your server is running Apache and supports mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

index.php is the file with your `$pageName = basename($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`

Comment: Wouldn't you know this is having problems with IE, anyone logging in gets kicked to the index.php page in IE.

Comment: In just IE? That's strange. You could post your code if you want and maybe we'll be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not provide a redirect header like this

header('Location:Your URL');

This has to be before any echo statements in the code.